# Model's- For uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am building an rails application in which users after they log in upload a document and then can download the document after it's finished. I am trying to create the model for a user being able to upload a document that works with paperclip

Would this model work as the model for uploading document's, I already have a user model

```
rails generate scaffold pdf description:string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your question, I'm guessing you're new to Rails, so I'll explain the uploading process for you:

---

**Models**

Uploading the files can be handled with Paperclip like this:

```
#app/models/document.rb
Class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user # -> allows you to call @user.documents
    has_attached_file :attachment #-> for Paperclip
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :documents # -> allows you to call @user.documents
end
```

Your data tables will look like this:

```
users
id | name | etc | etc | created_at | updated_at

documents
id | user_id | attachment_file_name | attachment_content_type | attachment_file_size | attachment_uploaded_at | created_at | updated_at
```

---

**Upload**

To upload the items you want, Paperclip basically creates a separate ActiveRecord object with the attachment inside

This means you have to call the uploads in your view, you need to call the object (method) on top of your `document` object:

```
@user.documents.each do |document|
    image_tag document.attachment.url #-> outputs the image
end
```

The way the upload process works is very simple:

```
#app/controllers/documents_controller.rb
def new 
    @document = Document.new
end

def create
    @document = Document.new(document_params)
    @document.save
end

private
def document_params
    params.require(:document).permit(:attachment).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

This will allow you to create this form:

```
#app/views/documents/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @document, html: { miltipart: true } do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
<% end %>
```

This will save the files in your DB & server, allowing you to access them throughout your views

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help. Would `rails generate model document` work for generating the document model?

Comment: No problem! And yes, the `rails g model document` will create the document model for you - you'll have to add `has_attached_file` yourself :)

Comment: Sorry to ask another question, I really appreciate all of the help! Would the data tables go into the `schema.rb`? Would the the document object also go inside of the `document.rb` file?

Comment: Hey buddy, nope the `schema.rb` file is for Rails (to specify which migrations it has performed). You don't need to touch it - I only wrote the schemas down to give you a template of which columns to use for your database tables :) `document.rb` *is* the object - when Rails / Ruby loads an instance of the `Document` Class, it creates an object which can then be used in your app. You just need to put what I've listed on the page into the file, and it should work for you